# Merging Mp3 files and keeping indices

Tags: mp3, concatenation

I have multiple Mp3 files:

```
0001.mp3
0002.mp3
........
9999.mp3
```

Each file has its own size/length which is different from the others.

I want to merge them into a single Mp3 file. In the same time keeping index file (txt, xml ...) that contains where each file is started in the output single file (BigOutput.mp3).

For example:

```
0001.mp3 starts at the 0        Byte of BigOutput.mp3
0002.mp3 starts at the 65874th  Byte of BigOutput.mp3
0003.mp3 starts at the 987485th Byte of BigOutput.mp3
and so on..
```

Is there any well-know solution/program for this purpose or I have to write my own?

Comment: You can use something like [Mp3Wrap](http://mp3wrap.sourceforge.net/) to 'concatenate' the MP3's, but I'm not sure ATM how to get the text output you want. If you only want that text in order to ease splitting the file later, then Mp3Wrap is perfect for you, because it's designed with that in mind and [Mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/) supports splitting Mp3Wrapped files back into their originating file sets.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bash solution. I have not actually tested this on real files, but it should work. You just read out the file size via the standard tools and add them together to get the current index. The first file is handled as a special case.

You would call this as a script with all file names provided as arguments in concatenation order.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

idx=0
idx_txt="idx.txt"

echo "$1 starts at 0" >$idx_txt
shift

for file in "$@" ; do
  idx=$(( idx + $(ls -l|grep "$file"|awk '{print $5}') ))
  echo "$file starts at $idx" >>$idx_txt
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much but doesn't Mp3 has headers and footer which will change the actual order of bytes?

Comment: I assumed you are really just `cat`ing them together since that seems to work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222225/using-cat-to-join-mp3-files-what-is-this-black-sorcery